# Show examples in tensorflow datasets not working

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I want to load the tensorflow [flowers](https://www.tensorflow.org/datasets/catalog/tf_flowers) dataset and visualize it using [tfds.show_examples](https://www.tensorflow.org/datasets/overview#visualize_a_dataset).

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import tensorflow_hub as hub
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds   
from tensorflow.keras import layers

import logging
logger = tf.get_logger()
logger.setLevel(logging.ERROR)

(train_examples, validation_examples), info = tfds.load(
    'tf_flowers', 
    with_info=True, 
    as_supervised=True, 
    split=['train[:70%]', 'train[70%:]'],
)

fig = tfds.show_examples(train_examples, info)
```

When I run my code, instead of seeing images, I get an error message:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-13-dcdedbcd800d> in <module>()
      6 )
      7 
----> 8 fig = tfds.show_examples(train_examples, info)

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_datasets/core/visualization.py in show_examples(ds_info, ds, rows, cols, plot_scale, image_key)
     68     # Infer the image and label keys
     69     image_keys = [
---> 70         k for k, feature in ds_info.features.items()
     71         if isinstance(feature, features_lib.Image)
     72     ]

AttributeError: 'DatasetV1Adapter' object has no attribute 'features'
```

Why is this not working?

Comment: Since tfds is a high-level wrapper for tf.data, I'd make sure that your tfds version is compatible with your tf version.

Comment: My TF is 2.2.0.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem using Colab. Try this

```
pip install --upgrade tensorflow-datasets
```

and restart the kernel