# AttributeError: 'ShuffleDataset' object has no attribute 'features'

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I am getting an error when trying to load a dataset in tensor-flow:

```
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds
ds, ds_info = tfds.load('eurosat/rgb:2.0.0',
                    with_info=True,
                    split='train',
                    data_dir='../input/eurosat',
                    download=False)
ds = ds.shuffle(1024)
tfds.show_examples(ds, ds_info);
```

Error message:

```
AttributeError: 'ShuffleDataset' object has no attribute 'features'
```

Source: https://www.tensorflow.org/datasets/api_docs/python/tfds/load

Comment: Similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62582022/show-examples-in-tensorflow-datasets-not-working

Comment: tensorflow version: 2.3.1

Answer (score 1):

To fix the package reversion on a Kaggle notebook make sure Internet is switched to On in the Settings panel to the right of the editor so the package can install.

```
!pip install -qU tensorflow-datasets
```